# Trying to run this program but I'm getting 'invalid syntax'

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

This program says hello and asks for my name.

```
print('Hello world!')

print('What is your name?')  #ask for their name
myName = input()

print('It is good to meet you, ' + myName)

print('The length of your name is:')

print(len(myName))

print('What is your age?')    #ask for their age
myAge = input()

print('You will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1 'in a year.')
```

But when I run it I get a `SyntaxError` here:

```
print('You will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1 'in a year.')
                                                     ^
```

Saying:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You are missing `)` on the last line.

Comment: Read carefully the message of interpreter, most of case, it give a line number with error, and then read carefully the line corresponding to the line number and then in 80% of case, errors are solved !

Answer (score 1):

The last line should read

```
print('You will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1 'in a year.'))
```

You were missing a closing parentheses.

Also, for future reference, in the `input()` function you can put in the string specifying to the user what they should type in, something like

```
myName = input('What is your name? ') #their name must be in quotes!
```

and

```
myAge = input('What is your age? ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your variables `myName` and `myAge`. Also you have a `SyntaxError` in the last line of your script where you have omitted a right parenthesis.

Try to erase the whole line and re-typing it all from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add an opening bracket at the beginning of the print and a closing bracket after + 1

print('Hello world!')

print('What is your name?')  #ask for their name
myName = input()

print('It is good to meet you, ' + myName)

print('The length of your name is:')

print(len(myName))

print('What is your age?')    #ask for their age
myAge = input()

print(('You will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1)) + 'in a year.')

Comment: You're right that a closing bracket is missing after `+ 1`, but why the one in the beginning?